# Adding, removing or modifying child elements - XML, JS, JQ only

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I understand how to retrieve the elements and write them to a document in JS with the HttpXMLRequest object but I can't seem to find any resources detailing how to modify it, I think the issue is that I don't actually know what the process is called so I can't search it. A lot of the questions already asked involve Java, C#, C++, php which I could probably manage - But I'm only able to use JS (And the DOM of course), JQuery and maybe some others like Xpath, but only if necessary. Is it possible?

Here's some example XML

```
<people>
  <person>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <age>20</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Jim</name>
  </person>
<people>
```

An example of what I need it to do (This is obviously for theoretical/learning purposes);
Add `<age>19</age>` to the `<person>` element where the `<name>` is Jim.
Completely remove the `<person>` and all children where the `<name>` is bob.
Adding a new `<person>` entirely with the `<name>` Tom and an `<age>` of 22.

I'm not asking for anybody to provide me fully working code, that would be a dicckk thing to do seeing as I've provided basically no code of my own - But does anybody know where I could find some documentation that may detail what it is I need to do? I was expecting sites like w3schools to get to it however they seem to skip it completely like it doesn't exist.

I do have some knowledge of JS/JQuery but detailed information about working with XML files seems to either be lacking, or, again I just don't know what to look for. The reason I'm limiting myself to XML/JS/JQ/DOM is mostly for compatibility.

Thanks a lot, and I'm sorry for not being able to provide any code :(

Comment: How are you retrieving the XML?

Comment: What do you mean by modify it? Save the changes or just to manipulate it before processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) for building the xml document. Then you can use getElementsByTagname, createElement, createTextNode and appendChild.

Then [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLSerializer) to to get back the xml as a string.

Comment: createElement/createTextNode/appendChild also be used to permanently modify the document?

Comment: @Dicckk Do you mean to permanently modify the document on the server?

Comment: @ other, I don't actually need to even see the XML document at this stage I just need a way of modifying it's elements with pre-built buttons. I want these buttons to be able to add/remove/change parts and save the XML file. If you really must know I'm using the DOMParser from W3schools, getElementsByTagName in combination with if statements and document.write()'s.

Comment: In my situation the document is local, but yeah, for example in the XML above, it needs to add `<age>20</age>` to the `<person>` with the `<name>` of Jim. Then actually make the change to the XML file permanent.

Comment: @Dicckk to save the xml file you'll need a server side script.

Comment: So nothing JS/JQ can do can ever make permanent changes to the document? Can it create a new document with the new changes + the old content and leave the old document alone? Is there ANYTHING client side that can do this?

Comment: @Dicckk the only thing that comes to mind is [ActiveXObject](http://www.google.com/search?q=activexobject+filesystemobject+javascript+save+file) in IE

Comment: Thanks for the info, marking your answer as correct cause it's the closest thing I'll probably get